# Strange behaviour of 'this' inside 'body' tag

Tags: javascript

I know using `inline javascript` is really a bad practice.

But Just for experimenting I was trying to do Something Like:

```
<body onclick="this.style.background='#ff0000';">
     Hello
</body>
```

And It is Working..

But the Problem Arises When

I do it like:

```
<body onload="this.style.background='#ff0000';">
     Hello
</body>
```

It Throws Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined`

But

```
<body onload="document.body.style.background='#ff0000';">
     Hello
</body>
```

Works Fine.

Can Any one Please Help Me in understanding, Why is this happening?

Is it because `body onload` internally translates to `window.onload`? (So that `window.style` becomes undefined?)

or It is something else?

Any Help, suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Yup, `this` refers to `Window`

Comment: *"Is it because body onload internally translates to window.onload?"*. Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the event is user-initiated, as in `onclick` which gets triggered once a user clicks, meaning the user is interacting directly, the `this` will have a reference to the element on which the event is bound, in this case, `body`

In the case of `onload`, it's not user-initiated event and hence `this` refers to the `window` object.

Comment: Thanks for spending your time in answering.. +1.

Comment: @VedantTerkar glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

As you've mentioned, When you try `onload`, `this` will refer to the window object.

```
<body onload="this.style.background='#ff0000';">
     Hello
</body>
```

You can try that using:

```
<body onload="console.log(this instanceof Window)">
```

Comment: Thanks for spending your time in answering.. +1.